# How to iterate map values which are in the form of lists in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

```
public class Students()
{
     private String title;
     private String name;


       //getters setters
}
```

I have a map 
`Map<String,List<Students>> mapList`

What i want to is, i send a key to get value from map and iterate that lists.

My approach

```
jsp
    <c:forEach items="${mapList['${title}']}" var="actualDetails">
                            //printing the values 
                    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do EL expressions inside EL expressions.

It's already an EL expression, so it should just be:

```
<c:forEach items="${mapList[title]}" var="actualDetails">
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose ${mapList} points to a `Map<String,List<Students>>`, then you can use the following EL expressions

```
   <c:forEach items="${mapList}" var="entry">
        ${entry.key}<br>
        <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="studentDetails">
              ${studentDetails.title}<br>
              ${studentDetails.name}<br>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```